# array return empty when trying to call from outside the function [swift]

Tags: swift, alamofire

I got this calling api function:

```
func searchResults(){


    let urlString = "http://dev.jocom.com.my/feed"


    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString , parameters: ["req" : "pro_name", "code" : searchString!])

        .responseData { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success:

                let apiSearchXML = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)

                for elem in apiSearchXML["rss"]["channel"]["item"]{
                    self.imageURL.append(elem["thumb_1"].element!.text!)

                    self.name.append(elem["name"].element!.text!)



                }
                print(self.name)

            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }

}
```

It seems ok when i print the output out, the array its containing something. But when i try to call it to display inside my collection view, it didnt return row, and it become empty, why is it?

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.name.count

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchResultsCollectionViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = "abc"
    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: The Alamofire Readme explicitly mentions that request are performed *asynchronously*. Have a look at the frequently asked [alamofire] questions: This has been asked and answered repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a completion handler for your `Async` call to complete and then you can fill the array with the results. I believe your `name` is an array of strings. Do like so:

```
func searchResults(complete: (names: [String]) -> ()){
let aVar = [String]()
//your code
for elem in apiSearchXML["rss"]["channel"]["item"]{

aVar.append(elem["name"].element!.text!)
}
complete(names: aVar)
//your code
}
```

Then when you call it, like so:

```
searchResults { theNames in
 print(theNames)
//Here you have your array of names, use how you want.
}
```

Comment: it works! thankyou so muchhhh :D

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

when you get a callback from the server.

Comment: where should i add it?

Comment: right before `print(self.name)`

Comment: no, its still not working

Comment: Did you run it on main thread?
If not, you can try this:
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 collectionView.reloadData()
  // update some UI
 });`

Comment: what should i do with the update some ui part?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Put this code right before `print(self.name)`

Answer (score 0):

"Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously."

This means that your request will complete some unknown amount of time after you call `searchResults`.

Your best strategy is to update your collection view within your success block.
(Make sure you make UI updates on the main thread.)

Comment: how should i do it? sorry, im very new in swift

Comment: can provide me any example?